# Installing Prophet (pystan build) on Docker container (buster)

Tags: debian, installation, build

I'd like to install [fbprophet](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/) in a Docker container. My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install fbprophet
```

Building the image errors on the "pip install fbprophet" step with this stack trace:

```
    Running setup.py install for fbprophet ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7ei5jssc/fbprophet_9a3a667ec353402389a02258feccfe51/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7ei5jssc/fbprophet_9a3a667ec353402389a02258feccfe51/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-741oj2zp/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.7m/fbprophet
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-7ei5jssc/fbprophet_9a3a667ec353402389a02258feccfe51/
    Complete output (10 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib
    creating build/lib/fbprophet
    creating build/lib/fbprophet/stan_model
    Importing plotly failed. Interactive plots will not work.
    INFO:pystan:COMPILING THE C++ CODE FOR MODEL anon_model_dfdaf2b8ece8a02eb11f050ec701c0ec NOW.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7ei5jssc/fbprophet_9a3a667ec353402389a02258feccfe51/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7ei5jssc/fbprophet_9a3a667ec353402389a02258feccfe51/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-741oj2zp/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.7m/fbprophet Check the logs for full command output.
```

There are a number of suggestions I've found online that I've tried unsuccessfully
(at this point I built the container without `fbprophet` and ran it, so I could try commands live):

1. [Here](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1306) the problem was that **gcc/g++ weren't installed**.

- I tried `apt install g++ gcc`, still fails to build (they were already installed)

2. pnmartinez's comment [here](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1057#issuecomment-729535603) suggests some **missing build tools**.

- I did `apt-get install build-essential libncursesw5-dev libreadline-gplv2-dev libssl-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libsqlite3-dev libbz2-dev libffi-dev zlib1g-dev` (after running `apt-get upgrade`, `apt-get update`, `apt-get dist-upgrade`), and retried with same result.

3. [This GH issue](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1057) suggests **downgrading to `pystan==2.18`**.

- Before [this commit](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/commit/0203a465f72d6f8166ec1cd3fbc2f9b05652b115#diff-b72f6e5561c432513e240838ae1eeb3f85237fa3ed5d701ad4c3be2a55c57b9d)
  introduced in v0.6, Prophet restricted itself to PyStan <=2.18.1, so I tried pip install prophet==0.5, which still failed. (I went all the way down to 0.2, still failed.) I then tried `pip3 uninstall pystan && pip3 install pystan==2.18 && pip3 install fbprophet==0.5` with the same result.

4. Install from conda-forge instead

- I looked into this, but installing a working conda env in a docker container seems pretty complicated

5. I also started trying to install on an Alpine-based container instead of Debian.

- I started running into issues there before the Prophet stage, and in general I would assume building a complicated C++ project won't be easier on a non-standard distro.

It appears that the problem occurs when gcc tries to build a PyStan model. My guess is that it is simply running out of memory (the `cc1plus` proc on `top` uses 2GB, about 90% of RAM, someone claims [here](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1193#issuecomment-550570156) it can use up to 8GB). However, this is pretty common software, and I succeeded in installing fbprophet with the same Dockerfile a few months back, so I'm not sure why this has become a problem. (I've tried building it both on macOS (Big Sur) and Linux (Fedora 33) with the same result.)

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out - as it was a memory issue, I just needed to allocate more memory to the Docker VM. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44533437/6220759) explains how to do it with the GUI. A lot of time wasted...

Comment: yes! I tried with 4G same error, 8GB did the trick. Thank you! I also wasted a lot of time on this one.

Comment: This worked for me on MacOS (Monterey) with Docker Desktop (Docker Engine `v20.10.7`). Increased memory from `4.5 GB` to `6.5 GB` and gave it `4 GB` of swap. `pystan` version `2.19.1.1`, `prophet` version `1.0.1`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, that's what I found - I gave 6 CPUs to Docker VM, so when it tries to build a code, GCC spawns 6 threads, each of them consuming too much RAM. I can say - even 16 Gb might be not enough. So, limiting the number of CPUs for the Docker VM by the, let's say, 4 CPU might be a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else having this issue, I was building with base image `python:3.7-slim` Changing to `python:3.7` fixed the issue

Comment: yes, just that simple.
man, this stuff gets complicated.
i'm simply trying to test 'auto-ts' but it has an fbprophet dependency.

thanks so much for posting that advice!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wanting to go the Conda route (OP's #4 idea and what worked best for me), here's how to do it:

```
FROM python:3-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Miniconda.
RUN wget --quiet 
https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest- 
Linux-x86_64.sh -O /tmp/install_miniconda.sh && \
 /bin/bash /tmp/install_miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda
ENV PATH=/opt/conda/bin:$PATH

# Install FB Prophet.
RUN conda install -c conda-forge Prophet
```

Answer (score 0):

With Mac OSX Big Sur 11.6

My Dockerfile includes

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pystan==2.19
RUN pip install fbprophet
```